# Nook read 37 files in ePub as 37 chapters instead of 11 in toc.ncx

Tags: epub, nook, ncx

Nook read 37 files in my ePub as 37 chapters instead of 11 chapters as set out in `toc.ncx` (NCX file) -- the ToC as presented by Nook lists filenames for all the chapters that do not have `navPoint / navLabel` set in `toc.ncx`, it looks like:

```
Chapter 1
f02.xhtml  
f03.xhtml  
Chapter 2
```

Chapter 1 and 2 are mapped to `f01.xhtml` and `f04.xhtml` respectively in the `.ncx` file.

Adobe Digital Editions and Calibre read the `toc.ncx` correctly, and have page breaks at new files (intended behavior). Any idea of a workaround? It appears to be Nook-specific.

`epubcheck-3.0b5` returned no errors.

Comment: Which Nook are you using? The different Nook devices all seem to have slightly different quirks--and Nook in general seems to be one of the quirkiest of the major reading systems.

Comment: @jorouke 1)How was the ePub created? 2) Can you provide a screenshot of the `.ncx` file and what it looks like in ADE?